# Ho can I check free time in time range

Tags: javascript, time, range

I have an array with different times registered

```
const existing = [
  {
    start: "2020-02-05T09:00:00Z",
    end: "2020-02-05T10:15:00Z"
  },
  {
    start: "2020-02-05T10:30:00Z",
    end: "2020-02-05T11:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    start: "2020-02-05T11:00:00Z",
    end: "2020-02-05T12:15:00Z"
  }
]
```

I want a function that return true or false, if it is possible to add another time.

If 10:00 - 11:00 is registered, it should also be possible to add 09:00-10:00. Meaning that start and end times can overlap.

The user might try to add these hours. But of cause they could choose many other hours

e.g. `newStart 09:59 - newEnd 10:20`

e.g. `newStart 10:16 - newEnd 10:29`

The problem is to compare the different objects but also time between the different objects. Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/every) may help to traverse the array of reserved time slots to find out whether those don't overlap requested:

```js
const reserved = [{start:"2020-02-05T09:00:00Z",end:"2020-02-05T10:15:00Z"},{start:"2020-02-05T10:30:00Z",end:"2020-02-05T11:00:00Z"},{start:"2020-02-05T11:00:00Z",end:"2020-02-05T12:15:00Z"}],
      bookingTimeInvalid = {start: '2020-02-05T09:59:00Z', end: '2020-02-05T10:20:00Z' },
      bookingTimeValid = {start: '2020-02-05T10:16:00Z', end: '2020-02-05T10:29:00Z' },
      
      validateBookingTime = ({start,end}, reserve) => 
        reserve.every(reserve => 
          new Date(reserve.start) >= new Date(end) ||
          new Date(reserve.end) <= new Date(start)
      )
      
console.log(`is 09:59-10:20 available? : `,validateBookingTime(bookingTimeInvalid, reserved))   
console.log(`is 10:16-10:29 available? : `,validateBookingTime(bookingTimeValid, reserved))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%}
```

Comment: looks interesting. I will check it out, and come back

Comment: ok. I have tried it out, and it works as expected. So thanks a lot. And also the code is pretty simple. There is a little error in your code, with shadowed variable name "reserve"

Answer (score 0):

You could create a consolidated time table where all overlapping times are merged.

In a later step, you could compare the wanted time agains the exiting time.

```js
const
    existing = [
        { start: "2020-02-05T09:00:00Z", end: "2020-02-05T10:15:00Z" },
        { start: "2020-02-05T09:00:00Z", end: "2020-02-05T09:08:00Z" },
        { start: "2020-02-05T10:30:00Z", end: "2020-02-05T11:00:00Z" },
        { start: "2020-02-05T11:00:00Z", end: "2020-02-05T12:15:00Z" }
    ],
    result = existing
        .reduce((r, { start, end }) => [...r, [start, true], [end, false]], [])
        .sort((a, b) => a[0] > b[0] || -(a[0] < b[0]) || b[1] - a[1])
        .reduce((count => (r, [time, isStart]) => {
            if (!count) r.push({ start: time });
            count += isStart || -1;
            if (!count) r[r.length - 1].end = time;
            return r;
        })(0), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```